# NoSQL Race Condition

Tags: concurrency, locking, race-condition, atomic, nosql

I'm trying to figure out how companies that use nosql database solve this general nosql race condition issue:

Lucky example: User and Product. Product has quantity of 1 and there are 2 users. When the first user tries to buy this product, system first checks whether quantity is > 0 and it is indeed > 0, proceeds to create a Transaction object and decrement quantity of product. The second user tries to buy the product, system rejects as quantity isn't > 0.

Unlucky: Both users try to buy the product simultaneously. For both, system confirmed quantity is > 0 and so created a Transaction object for both users, hence destroying the company image next day...

How to generally deal with this common scenario?

From similar cases i found on the net, one suggested solution is to use request queue, and process the request one by one. However, if all transactions are queued, and you're running business like Amazon (millions of transactions every now and then), how do we expect users to know whether or not their purchase succeeded shortly after they clicked that purchase now button?

Answer (score -1):

One of the ways to solve this problem is to allow both users to order products simultaneously.

Then there are two possible situations:

1. One of the users doesn't finish a transaction (refuses to pay, closes a browser window etc). Then another one will have the requested amount of a product.
2. Both users finished their transactions. Then you will get a random user your product and say sorry to another one giving away a coupon with $10 to him/her.

The second situation should happen extremely rare. So you won't blow out all your money on coupons and your users will be happy whatever the outcome. But you still need to monitor the 2nd situation in order to react and make changes to your system if it happens more often than you expected.

Comment: I think it's a really bad idea to shape business processes around your technological limitations like you propose in option 2. Giving coupons instead of the ordered products destroys the company's image. Simply don't use NoSQL if ACID transactions are important.

Comment: The question is how would ACID help us? If one user has started a purchasing process and blocked the last unit of product then the other one has to wait until the first one has finished a process (funny thing is that it can takes hours or even more) or has to be immediately denied, although that last unit is still in storage.

Comment: Okay, but then I'm not so sure why to lock a product for a user which is away for hours. My point being was that the coupon idea is a business solution for a technological problem, that seems like a misfit.

Comment: If you don't lock a product then a user comes back at some point and faces the problem that transaction has been aborted which can also result in destroying company's image. Also, a business solution for a technological problem is a popular case these days. A couple years ago I witnessed a situation when there were two guys having boarding passes with the same seat. So the airline (United Airlines) offered one of them a business class seat instead of a coach. Business solution for a tech problem. It's better to fix a tech problem, but if you can't then that is better then nothing.

Comment: On your second case I agree.